# Make layout panels, close panels

Tags: interface, 3d-view

Since these questions are closely related I put them in 1 post, but else I can separate the questions into multiple posts :)

For example I have this layout:
[image]

- If I move border 3 to the left, it cannot be moved further than border 2. Is there a way to move border 3 such that it 'pushes' border 2 to the left as well? (Same if I want to move border 2 in the direction of border 3)
- I would like to close the middle panel by border 2, but I can't because on the left there are 2 panels. How can this be achieved?
- Can I make 1 panel at border 1, such that it is next to 3D view panel AND timeline panel? But I can only make a panel that shares space with either the 3D view panel OR the timeline panel (Same for border 4)

This are multiple questions, but I can separate them if I have to. :)

Comment: I wrote a proposal for this on the wiki a while back: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Proposals/UI/Area_Splitting

Comment: When did you write it? And did they do something about it? :)

Comment: I remember brecht saying something like it would be nice to have and the only reason it doesn't do any of that is because the devs are busy with other projects. So in short, need more devs :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, this isn't currently possible in Blender.